# Xbox One wireless controller loses connection when I move it more than a few feet from laptop

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, xbox-one

I've got a Dell XPS 15 9570 with ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. The controller pairs fine, and when i'm using it right next to my laptop it works fine. However, when I take it even a few feet away it seems to lose it's stable connection, most button presses are not received.

It seems to get worse when I point the controller away from the machine as well, which makes no sense to me if it's connecting with bluetooth.

I tested the controller with my windows 10 pc and the issue is not happening, it works flawlessly there. I've also used a dualshock 4 controller with my ubuntu laptop and that worked flawlessly as well.

Does anyone have any ideas for a fix?

Comment: Sounds like a limitation with your internal bluetooth adapter. Newer external USB bluetooth adapters have a better distance.

Comment: I got a 9570 at the beginning of this year, and the Bluetooth/wireless AIO adapter that the laptop shipped with was abysmal at best. I had similar issues that you are describing, but with my Bluetooth headphones. My fix was replacing the Qualcomm adapter with [this one](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B079QJQF4Y/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). I would not recommend replacing the hardware right now, but if updating the drivers doesn't help, and all else fails, it may be something to consider.

Comment: Let's check your BIOS version. In `terminal` type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. If it's not 1.13, go to https://www.dell.com/support/home/ca/en/cadhs1/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=fpcc0&oscode=wt64a&productcode=xps-15-9570-laptop and get/install the newer version. Report back.